# Can a corrupted heap be cleaned up?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, free, delete-operator

If I corrupt my heap, can I clean it up afterwards? If yes, how?

Example for a heap corruption:

```
int *x = new int; // If we allocate memory wit new, we have to free it later.. 
x++;
*x = 1; // the heap is now corrupted
```

However, calling `free(x)`, `delete x` etc. will crash above's code. Can the memory still be somehow deallocated or is it already broken beyond hope?

Comment: Its destroyed. Gone. Start over and don't do these things again.

Comment: Generally no, once you've corrupted memory there's really no way to get back to the state where it was before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I corrupt my heap, can I clean it up afterwards?

No you can't fix this. Basically your program has *undefined behavior*. A *heap corruption* is something detected by some sanitizer tools running your code in debug mode.

There's no way to undo `*x = 1;` or to restore the value that was residing there before.

---

> However, calling free(x), delete x etc. will crash above's code.

Sure, you're trying to free something you never allocated.

> Can the memory still be somehow deallocated or is it already broken beyond hope?

It's broken beyond any hope.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will accept your answer later.

Comment: But I think there is stuff allocated - x has in fact a size of 8. It should just have a size of 4. Does it crash now, because it expects the size of 4 or because the address of the 2nd integer was not marked previously as allocated memory?

Comment: @Imago `new` usually allocates larger chunks behind the scenes, your code has _undefined behavior_ though, and you're not allowed to rely on such implementation details.

Comment: I see :/, I am just trying to understand the concept of pointers better.. I read about pointers and wondered what would happen.. most tutorials do not seem to cover it in detail..